# Why "de" in "de quelle couleur est..."?

Tags: grammaire

Why do you say "De quelle couleur est ta chemise" instead of "Quelle couleur est ta chemise"?

Must you always say "de"?

I have seen "Quelle couleur est ta chemise?" many times, but I think it is an incorrect direct translation from English.

Answer (score 7):

If you think about it, the English is pretty strange. "What colour is your shirt?" But your shirt isn't a colour; it has a colour! :)

In general, adjectival predicates can't be asked about using "quel" (what/which).

> ✓ La chemise est bleue.
> ✗ Quelle couleur est la chemise ? Bleu.

But you could ask about the colour as a property:

> ✓ Quelle est la couleur de la chemise ? Bleu.

And you can also use *de*, which in this case means "having / being characterized by":

> ✓ De quelle couleur est la chemise ?

The *chemise* has a colour, is of a certain colour. It could be compared to older, more poetic English expressions like "[trees of green, skies of blue, clouds of white](https://youtu.be/-Aba0lVdE2c?si=9iGiKfckvuk07gkV)".

Comment: You could also say "Quelle couleur a ta chemise?"

Comment: @SimonMourier ça sonne moins bien mais oui c'est grammaticalement juste.

Comment: https://www.laculturegenerale.com/couleur-bleu-couleur-bleue-orthographe/

Comment: @Personne C'est de la torture, pure et simple... (anglicisme? :) )

Comment: « Attention, un train peut en cacher un autre » : quand on franchit une barrière, le **is** d'état devient le **a** d'avoir, ET l'accord de *bleu* avec *couleur* barre la route qui mène à l'Académie française.

Comment: … Firefox inclus un correcteur d'orthographe intelligent…

Comment: @Personne Aucun correcteur d'orthographe ne répond à cette description ...